# How to update the "bytes written" count in custom Spark data source?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created a Spark Data Source that uses the "older" DataSource V1 API to write data in a specific binary format our measuring devices and some software requires, i.e., my `DefaultSource` extends `CreatableRelationProvider`.

In the appropriate `createRelation` method I call my own custom method to write the data from the `DataFrame` passed in. I am doing this with the help of Hadoop's FileSystem API, initialized from the Hadoop `Configuration` one can pull out of the supplied `DataFrame`:

```scala
  def createRelation(sqlContext: SQLContext,
                     mode      : SaveMode,
                     parameters: Map[String, String],
                     data      : DataFrame): BaseRelation = {
    val path = ... // get from parameters; in real here is more preparation code, checking save mode etc.
    MyCustomWriter.write(data, path)
    EchoingRelation(data) // small class that just wraps the data frame into a BaseRelation with TableScan
  }
```

In the `MyCustomWriter` I then do all sorts of things, and in the end, I save data as a side effect to `map`, `mapPartitions` and `foreachPartition` calls on the executors of the cluster, like this:

```scala
val confBytes = conf.toByteArray // implicit I wrote turning Hadoop Writables to Byte Array, as Configuration isn't serializable

data.
  select(...).
  where(...).
  // much more
  as[Foo].
  mapPartitions { it =>
    val conf = confBytes.toWritable[Configuration] // vice-versa like toByteArray
    val writeResult = customWriteRecords(it, conf) // writes data to the disk using Hadoop FS API
    writeResult.iterator
  }.
  // do more stuff
```

While this approach works fine, I notice that when running this, the `Output` column in the Spark job UI is not updated. Is it somehow possible to propagate this information or do I have to wrap the data in `Writable`s and use a Hadoop `FileOutputFormat` approach instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky approach.

Inside a RDD/DF operation you can get `OutputMetrics`:

```scala
val metrics = TaskContext.get().taskMetrics().outputMetrics
```

This has the fields `bytesWritten` and `recordsWritten`. However, the setters are package-local for `org.apache.spark.executor`. So, I created a "breakout object" in the package:

```scala
package org.apache.spark.executor

object OutputMetricsBreakout {

  def setRecordsWritten(outputMetrics: OutputMetrics,
                        recordsWritten: Long): Unit =
    outputMetrics.setRecordsWritten(recordsWritten)

  def setBytesWritten(outputMetrics: OutputMetrics,
                      bytesWritten: Long): Unit =
    outputMetrics.setBytesWritten(bytesWritten)
}
```

Then I can use:

```scala
val myBytesWritten = ... // calculate written bytes

OutputMetricsBreakout.setBytesWritten(metrics, myBytesWritten + metrics.bytesWritten)
```

This is a hack but the only "simple" way I could come up with.